# Render ByteBuffer LWJGL 3

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, bytebuffer

I'm currently trying to learn, how to program with LWJGL 3, and there are not a lot of tutorials/books/documentations about it (not just in java, but in C too). I got over most of these problems, but I couldn't find any materials about how to render with ByteBuffers or how to convert them into textures. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have any code? What did you try so far?

Comment: I have set up a method for loading up textures in ByteBuffers (with PNGDecoder), it returns a ByteBuffer.

Comment: You can have a look at the [LWJGL 3 demos](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/tree/master/modules/core/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo), which show you how to do many common things. The [stb/Image demo](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/master/modules/core/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo/stb/Image.java) has an example on how to load textures with STB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I found out, that you can use the `glTexImage2D` method, to store a ByteBuffer in a texture.